# Another stuck on proof of theorem 8.5 in baby rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

At first following is Theorem 8.5 and its proof in Rudin.

[image]

I don't know why we need the process from "Let A" to "desired conclusion".
Actually without it, Rudin just show that $f(x)=0\ \ \ for \ \ \    |x|<|x-x_0|+|x_0|<R$. why we should derive set $A$ is open???

Answer (score 1):

Before that paragraph, what is known is $\forall x \in E$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n =0,$$

It is not yet known is $\forall x \in S$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n =0,$$

Note that $S$ is connected. Hence we are not supposed to be able to write it as disjoint union of two non-empty open sets. If we have shown both $A$ and $B$ are both open, disjoint and their union is $S$, then one of them must be empty. Hence, we can show that $S=A$.

Comment: Without we derivate $A$ is open, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n=0$ imply $c_n=0\ \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, from (7)$f^{(k)}(0)=k! c_k$

Comment: I don't know why the truth that A is open is important here.

Comment: edited the answer.

Comment: Actually, $A=S$ because $A$ is open, however without the fact $A$ is open, Rudin derive $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n(x-x_0)^n=0\ \ for\  |x|-|x_0|\leq |x-x_0|<R-|x_0|, |x|<R$, in other words, for S from a limit point $x_0$...

Comment: that is part of process to show that $A$ is open.

Comment: He claim that $d_n=0,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, in \ |x|<R$, he just derive $ $f(x)=0\ \ in \ S$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference.  He proved $d_n=0$ for which (22) holds.

Comment: Yes (22) hold $|x|\leq |x-x_0|+|x_0|<R,\ \ S$

Comment: @백주상, for your very first comment, we do not know yet that $f^{(k)}(0)=0$, hence can't conclude $c_k=0$

Answer (score 0):

In the proof, Rudin just assumed that A was open by a sentence:"Suppose we can prove that A is open."
And he proceeded the proof to the conclusion.
Thus, the last thing he had to do was to prove that A was open.